# Change account expiration date in "active directory" using Unbound Id?

Tags: java, active-directory, ldap, unboundid-ldap-sdk

I am trying to change the `account expiration date` in windows `active directory`.

I can able to change the ***Never*** option in account expiry using the below code .

```
final Modification mod = new Modification(ModificationType.REPLACE,
        "accountExpires", "9223372036854775807");//Can change the required date with milliseconds

LDAPResult result=connection.modify(userDN, mod);
```

But , If I tried to change the `account expiry date` means  , the code executed successfully and success was printed in console . But the date is not changed in the `AD`.

Here is my code to change or extend the account expiry date.

public class AccountExpireSetting {

```
public void ChangeAccountExpires(String userDN,String password , String dateToChange) throws LDAPException
{
    LDAPConnection connection=null;
    String someDate = null;
    try {
        connection = new LDAPConnectionObject().getConnection();
    } catch (LDAPException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }


    try{
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy");
        Date date = sdf.parse(dateToChange);
        System.out.println("Date to MillSeconds : "+date.getTime());
        someDate = String.valueOf(date.getTime());

        Date date1=new Date(date.getTime());
        System.out.println("MillSeconds to Date : "+date1);
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try{

        System.out.println("Going to replace account expires to never");
        final Modification mod = new Modification(ModificationType.REPLACE,
                "accountExpires", someDate);// 9223372036854775807 milliseconds can change the password to never expire
        // 9223372036854775807  

        LDAPResult result=connection.modify(userDN, mod);
        System.out.println("Account expires status : " + result); // Password status : LDAPResult(resultCode=0 (success), messageID=2, opType='modify')
    }catch(LDAPException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        System.out.println("Error in replacing account expires to never");  

        e.printStackTrace();
    }finally
    {
        System.out.println("Closing the connection.");
        connection.close();
    }  
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String temp="CN=Anand,OU=Java,OU=Chennai,OU=Department,dc=tstdmn,dc=com";
    try {
        new AccountExpireSetting().ChangeAccountExpires(temp, "password@123","08.06.2014");
    } catch (LDAPException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

}

Hope you people will give a better solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The acountExpires is not milliseconds but rather the number of 100 nanosecond intervals since January 1, 1601 (UTC).

If a user object in Active Directory has never had an expiration date, the accountExpires attribute is set to a huge number. The actual value is 2^63 – 1, or 9,223,372,036,854,775,807. This is because 64-bit numbers can range from -2^63 to 2^63 - 1, making this the largest number that can be saved as a 64-bit value. Obviously this represents a date so far in the future that it cannot be interpreted. In fact, AccountExpirationDate raises an error if it attempts to read this value. If a user object has an expiration date, and then you remove this date in ADUC by selecting "Never" on the "Account" tab, the GUI sets accountExpires to 0. Thus, the values 0 and 2^63 - 1 both really mean "Never"

For one way to change in Java try [looking at this discussion](https://community.oracle.com/thread/1157460).

-jim

Comment: Thanks it helped.But the date assigning for account expire will be assigned one day before. For example , If i tried to change date to jan 15,2015 means it will assigned to jan 14,2015. Please help me.

Comment: I do not follow what you are trying to say is the problem. How are you assigning the date? What code are you using?

Comment: Thanks you have solved my problem. +1 for you . Can you please help me here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24164752/how-to-retrieve-windows-active-directory-attributes-ids-in-java ?